# hydro + kinect + Ubuntu 12.04 library issue?

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use ROS Hydro to launch a Kinect in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I installed the proper packages using:
sudo apt-get-install ros-hydro-openni-camera ros-hydro-openni-launch

However, when I run
$roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch I get this error with ROS Hydro:
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib//libopenni_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z

It seems to me that the path is wrong because it contains two //'s in a row before libopenni_nodelet.so  but I have no idea where I should fix the problem.

Thanks for your time in advance.
--Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123421/hydro-+-kinect-+-ubuntu-12.04-library-issue?/) by [gt-mike](https://answers.ros.org/users/11361/gt-mike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tip: type this in your shell:

```
c++filt _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
```

This will allow you to see the missing symbol in human-readable format:

```
ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)
```

This process is called [demangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).
Now, your system is not able to find this symbol in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so` or the shared libraries it's linked to. You can confirm that you don't have it in your installed ROS libraries by typing:

```
nm -D /opt/ros/hydro/lib/*.so | grep -i "T _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z"
```

In my case (working Hydro), I get (in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole.so`):

```
0000000000016530 T _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
```

Conclusion: there must be an error in the package (not up-to-date or missing shared library dependency). Check that you are up-to-date as advised by @ahendrix, and if the problem persists, you may want to contact the developers and/or packagers.

### Update

Here's a script that can help you find a given symbol in a given library directory:

#### find_symbol.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# First argument: library folder (e.g. /opt/ros/hydro/lib)
# Second argument: mangled symbol (e.g. _ZN3ros7console8shutdownEv)
for lib in $(find $1 -name \*.so) ; do
    res=`nm -D $lib | grep $2 | grep -v " U "`
    if [ ! -z "$res" ]; then
        echo "$lib: $res"
    fi
done
```

Then run (for instance):

```
./find_symbol.sh /opt/ros/hydro/lib _ZN3ros7console8shutdownEv
```

Output:

> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole.so: 0000000000015e00 T _ZN3ros7console8shutdownEv

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path looks fine; the OS will collapse multiple '//'s together automatically.

It looks like the real issue here is ABI breakage in one of the underlying libraries; probably the call to ros::console::print(). I think rosconsole underwent some ABI changes recently, and it's possible that the version you have isn't up to date.

Try running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install the latest versions of the ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rand](https://answers.ros.org/users/2393/rand/) on 2014-02-19**:
I had the exact same problem as bchr, and this solved it. I think this should be the accepted answer.